# How to replace <b> with <strong> in TinyMCE for Plone

Tags: tinymce, plone

I would like to replace bold tag, , with strong tag,  in TinyMCE. How to do it in Plone using Products.TinyMCE?

I read TinyMCE document, http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_elements. Below is how to do it in TinyMCE:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    valid_elements : "strong/b"
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I never tested this change, however you can try what you learned patching "tiny_mce_init.js".

To do this I suggest to use z3c.jbot (see also http://blog.keul.it/2011/06/z3cjbot-magical-with-your-skins.html).

Answer (score 2):

You may do this using the tinymce configuration:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    extended_valid_elements : "strong/b",
    ....
    // Override internal formats  
    formats: {
    bold : {inline : 'strong' }
    },
    ...
});
```

In case you have editor content already saved in the database with b-tags it might be needed to replace those tags on serverside with strong-tags.

Answer (score 1):

Both [keul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681548/keul) and [Thariama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346063/thariama) answers are correct. I have to combine both answers in order for TinyMCE working in Plone.

Here is how I do it,
- patching/overriding "tiny_mce_init.js" with the name "Products.TinyMCE.skins.tinymce.tiny_mce_init.js" using z3c.jbot.

```
function TinyMCEConfig(id) {
  ...
  this.init = function() {
    ...
    var init_dict = {
      ...
      fix_list_elements : false,

      extended_valid_elements : "strong/b",
      // Override internal formats  
      formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'strong' }
      }
    };
    ...
  };    
  ...      
}
```